# Ubuntu 18.04 Bluetooth detects SOME devices. Used to work

Tags: sound, bluetooth

I am quite new to the Linux world, so, apologies if the question is redundant.

I am running on Ubuntu 18.04. My bluetooth used to detect and connect perfectly to my speakers. For some reason, does not anymore.

It detects and connects to my phone and to another laptop. However, it fails to do so with any other audio devices, like Samsung Soundbar and Taotronics btt-br05 bluetooth receiver.

I tried rebooting both the laptop and the bluetooth drivers, as well as installing blueman, with no luck.

Any ideas what is going on,or where to look for a solution next?

Thank you